# error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in ARQoid SPARQL Query

Tags: java, android, sparql

Please help me out... 
I am using ARQoid in Android Studio, I imported all jars from the ARQoid project.

The code is below. The sparql query is no problem, I tested the endpoint.

```
    String sparqlEndpoint = "http://XXX/sparql";
    String sparqlQuery = "PREFIX bf: <http://bibframe.org/vocab/> "
            + "SELECT  * "
            + "WHERE {?s ?p ?o. "
            + "?s bf:label ?u. "
            + "filter (lang(?u) = \"chs\" && regex(?u,\"^k\")).}";
    // create the Jena query using the ARQ syntax (has additional support for SPARQL federated queries)
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
```

this line "Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery, Syntax.syntaxARQ);" is where I get an error

The full errors are here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory$Impl.createProperty(ResourceFactory.java:245)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory.createProperty(ResourceFactory.java:121)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.property(RDF.java:32)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.<clinit>(RDF.java:45)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.ARQConstants.<clinit>(ARQConstants.java:31)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.<clinit>(ARQ.java:40)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query.<clinit>(Query.java:54)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:71)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:43)
at shldata.getNames(shldata.java:29)
at shldata.main(shldata.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:9)
    at org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerFactory.getLogger(AndroidLoggerFactory.java:69)
    at org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerFactory.getLogger(AndroidLoggerFactory.java:44)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.PropertyImpl.<clinit>(PropertyImpl.java:64)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logging setup is failing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:9)
    at org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerFactory.getLogger(AndroidLoggerFactory.java:69)
```

You'll need to put in a slf4j provider (the default "print to system.err" may work enough - Jena does not print anything by default).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your app as an Android application on an Android device or emulator. You cannot run it as a regular Java app if it has any Android dependencies.

The exception message

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

comes from the version of Android platform JAR stub that is good for compiling with but cannot be used at runtime.